# How to start using installed Firebug?

Tags: firebug

I have downloaded firebug from this page:

http://getfirebug.com/

(I use Firefox), but I don't know how to start using it - no icon on the desktop, no changes on the Firefox interface, so what should I do in order to start using firebug?

Comment: Also make sure you have restarted firefox first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a firefox extension you have to install it into firefox. Cross-check in your addon settings.

Then you should see a small firebug icon in the lower right of your window in the status bar. Click it to open the interface. Usually <kbd>F12</kbd> also opens it.

Comment: Oh, I see it here!!!! Thanks a lot, honk!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Firebug is a Firefox extension, not a separate application. If you load a webpage in Firefox, you can right-click on any element within the page and choose **Inspect Element**. The Firebug panel will open, with the HTML view highlighting the code for the element you right-clicked on. You can easily navigate the panel from there.